# How to find repeated letters in the same word in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve a [challenge](https://py.checkio.org/en/mission/stressful-subject/) for finding some pattern in a given string. First idea came to my mind is to loop over the characters and find the pattern.

(A "stressful" subject line means that all letters are in uppercase, and/or ends by at least 3 exclamation marks, and/or contains at least one of the following “red” words: "help", "asap", "urgent". Any of those "red" words can be spelled in different ways - "HELP", "help", "HeLp", "H!E!L!P!", "H-E-L-P", even in a very loooong way "HHHEEEEEEEEELLP")

Someone submitted below code for that and I don't understand what's going on. How does this work?

```
return (subj.isupper() or
    subj.endswith('!!!') or
    any(re.search('+[.!-]*'.join(c for c in word), subj.lower())
        for word in ['help', 'asap', 'urgent']))
```

Comment: The requirements in your question don't seem to completely line up with your question title.  What is the point of the question, and what are you trying to find?

Comment: I think it fails to match repeats of the last character, like urgentttt.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Yeah it does fail as `+` is not greedy, but I think that is not really important to match this as it returns `True` anyway :)

Comment: @BlueSheepToken: ah right, it'll just match 'urgent' and that there are more characters is irrelevant, didn't think of that.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, Sorry if the title was misleading, The code submitted aims to find the repeated characters in certain words. I was trying to find mainly an explanation for the third part of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is just checking if any of the 3 conditions are met,

- The first one `sub.isupper()` returns `True` if every character are uppercase
- The second one `subj.endswith('!!!')` check if the word ends with `!!!`
- The third one is using regular expression to match red words and the method `any` to check if any red word is matched

#### For part

For each `red word` (`for word in ['help', 'asap', 'urgent']`), the word is converted in lower case and is used to generate a regular expression.

#### Regex part

For instance `'+[.!-]*'.join(c for c in 'help')` gives `h+[.!-]*e+[.!-]*l+[.!-]*p` Which checks for every letters of the word, repeated as many times as wanted, and all letters are separated by either `.`, `!` or `-` as many times as wanted.

#### Any part

And finally, `any` returns `True` if any of the bool of the generator is `True`. So if the regex matches any of the red words.

Comment: Thx @BlueSheepToken, the regex part was a mystery but it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

If we take the example of the word "help":

`subj.isupper()` returns true if `subj="HELP"`

`subj.endswith('!!!')` returns true if `subj="help!!!"`

`subj.lower()` forces the string into lowercase `subj="HelP"`-> `subj="help"`

`re.search('+[.!-]*'.join(c for c in word)` joins/removes occurences of the same characters next to each other, for instance, it will transform "heeellp" into "help"